# Select count of rows matching a condition grouped by increments of Id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table that has an autoincremented numeric primary. I'm trying to get a count of rows that match a condition grouped by increments of their primary key. Given the data:

```
| id | value |
|----|-------|
| 1  |   a   |
| 2  |   b   |
| 3  |   a   |
| 4  |   a   |
| 5  |   b   |
| 6  |   a   |
| 7  |   b   |
| 8  |   a   |
| 9  |   b   |
| 10 |   b   |
| 11 |   a   |
| 12 |   b   |
```

If I wanted to know how many rows matched `value = 'a'` for every five rows, the result should be:

```
| count(0) |
|----------|
|    3     |
|    2     |
|    1     |
```

I can nest a series of subqueries in the `SELECT` statement, like such:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(0) 
FROM table 
WHERE value = 'a' 
AND id > 0 
AND id <= 5) AS `1-5`,
(SELECT count(0)
FROM table
WHERE value = 'a'
AND id > 5
AND id <=10) AS `6-10`,
...
```

But is there a way to do this with a `GROUP BY` statement or something similar where I don't have to manually write out the increments? If not, is there a more time efficient method than a series of subqueries in the `SELECT` statement as in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could divide the ID by 5 and then [`ceil`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) the result:

```
SELECT   CONCAT((CEIL(id / 5.0) - 1) * 5, '-', CEIL(id / 5.0) * 5), COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
WHERE    value = 'a'
GROUP BY CEIL(id / 5.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following aggregated query should do the trick :

```
SELECT CEIL(id/5), COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE value = 'a'
GROUP BY CEIL(id/5)
```